# Consider the Matrix $A$, Find $A^{100}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the Matrix 
$A$ = $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & 8 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right)$

or

$A$ = $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & -1 & 0 \\
8 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right)$

(a) Find $A^{100}$

Comment: Surely this problem comes up right after diagonalization. Can you diagonalize this matrix? Do you see how diagonalizing this matrix helps you?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Matrices [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023/290196).

Comment: This is ridiculous. Have you even tried finding $A^2$? If you did you would know the answer to your question!

Comment: I guess I take back my words, but not really. Leaving that comment up.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&8\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} $ denote as I.

By association law of multiplication and the identity of identity, namely $A^{100} = (A^2)^{50} = I^{50} = I $